# How would I boot Linux from a hard drive that was previously dual boot with windows?

Tags: linux, dualboot

I had a dual boot system with Windows and Ubuntu. I had to reset the windows (main) drive by essentially doing a clean install, but now my Linux drive is just essentially storage until I can figure out a way to boot into Linux. Is there any way to make the Linux drive bootable without a reinstall/reset to where I can keep all my stuff in that drive?

Comment: You should be backing up your data from both Windows & Linux, so a reinstall is not a big issue. UEFI or BIOS installs? If UEFI, you can just boot from UEFI boot menu. If BIOS install Windows install may have removed Linux partitions from partition table, but data is still there and you just need to restore entry in partition table.

Comment: Reinstall a bootloader (e.g. grub)